# Multiscreen support in Phonegap and image sizes for android, iphone, windows blackberry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

Currently i am developing phonegap project with % size in css, the icons used are get blurred in some screens how to handle this problem please guide me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stretch and fit images for any possible screen you can use vector (SVG) icons. More information about SVG support here: http://caniuse.com/svg

Since certain mobile Webkit versions doesn't support SVG you can fall back to custom font with icons. If it is OK for you to use black-and-white only icons, you can use custom font to make vector icons. Example: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/